gnuplot: How to display time series over a boxplot?
I would like to visualize the change of certain data over time. For this purpose, I would like to display the time courses of the two blocks (cross/long) as points that are connected by a line above the boxes of the reference data. Neighboring plots should not overlap. So how can I define or construct the time scale?
reset session

files          = "data.dat reference.dat"

# File "reference.dat" contains only index / block "norm"
ref_blocks     = "norm"

$REF<<EOD
# norm
RH   LH   RA   LA
12019.1 444.6   16159.2 62355.9
8256.7  171.9   18879.5 67602.1
7560.4  192.7   15405.6 59350.9
13985.5 542.3   18920   56517.7
5401.5  364.9   13164.1 48907.4
3856.3  375.8   15093   73012.8
9087.7  532.8   15255.4 52057.8
8948.1  313.4   13690.2 53685.8
6511    275.3   11455.2 45066
10404.1 264.6   15223.6 60208.2
EOD


# File "data.dat" contains indices / blocks "cross long"
blocks         = "cross long"

$DAT<<EOD
# cross
date      RH        LH        RA        LA
20200203  9500.8    164.3     13004.2   54644.1
20200522  9940.9    203.6     20142.7   49401.3
20210521  11226.3   222.7     14085.7   54759
20220527  13605.5   380.1     19472.8   46403.6
20220701  13206.5   376.3     12784     53552.9
20220706  13148.9   272.6     13455.7   51796.4
20221006  13832.9   311.6     13006.1   52337.4
20230309  13389.8   310.5     12677     54125.9
20230907  13806.3   334.8     13381.2   54700.4
20240919  15376.2   492.4     13050.4   53682.1


# long
date      RH        LH        RA        LA
20200203  9070.1    236.9     5505.8    53849.7
20200522  9489.2    258.5     6505.8    54003.9
20220527  13466     441.1     14128.5   50221.7
20220701  12934.3   400.4     14421.3   52927
20220706  12921.9   386.5     14539.9   50843.7
20221006  13440.1   351.2     15709.2   50322.8
20230309  13258.9   362.8     14416.2   52378.4
20210521  10771.3   294.8     14199.1   53795.7
20230907  13369.6   376.7     14974.9   53158.1
20240919  15216     478.7     14213     51990.8


EOD

# Both files contain columns with header names / labels "RH LH RA LA"
labels         = "RH LH RA LA"
myXtic(n)      = sprintf( "%s", word( labels, n ) )

set style fill solid 0.25 border -1
set style boxplot outliers pointtype 7
set style data boxplot
set boxwidth 0.7 absolute

set title "dat -> ref" font "Arial,14"
set xtics 1, 1, words(labels) scale 0
#set datafile separator '\t'

plot for [i=1:words(labels)] $REF index "norm" using (i):( column( word( labels, i ) ) ) notitle

#replot for [label in labels] $DAT index "long" using (i):( column( label ) ) notitle

Edit: Yes, there should be one timeline per box. All boxes should have the same color and there should be one color for all cross-values and one color for all long-values.

Edit 2:


Not sure, if I completely understand what you want. I understand that you want on top of each of the four boxplots (based on $REF data) a time axis linespoint graph based on $DAT (cross/long) data, correct? So, is actually one timescale plot over the whole graph or one shifted timescale plots over each of the four boxes? A handsketch would certainly help.

I have just edited my post to clarify.

Thanks for the freehand sketch. I guess it much clearer now. So, you don't need date tics on the x-axis? And should the time point intervals be to scale or just equidistant to show the trend?

Scaled distances would be nice especially in cases with only a few boxes (there can be 2-24 boxes)

I will add hypertext labels with detailed information for each point. And I do not need xtics for time

Here is a suggestion. Once you know the time range via stats you need to scale and shift your time data to the position and width of each of the boxplots.

not sure, why xtic() doesn't seem to work together with boxplot, so you have to do it "manually" via a dummy plot (NaN)
for your data over two orders of magnitude, logscale y might be helpful

Check the following minimized example as starting point for further optimization.
Script:
### overlay boxplots with timedata
reset session

$REF<<EOD
# norm
RH   LH   RA   LA
12019.1 444.6   16159.2 62355.9
8256.7  171.9   18879.5 67602.1
7560.4  192.7   15405.6 59350.9
13985.5 542.3   18920   56517.7
5401.5  364.9   13164.1 48907.4
3856.3  375.8   15093   73012.8
9087.7  532.8   15255.4 52057.8
8948.1  313.4   13690.2 53685.8
6511    275.3   11455.2 45066
10404.1 264.6   15223.6 60208.2
EOD

$DAT<<EOD
# cross
date      RH        LH        RA        LA
20200203  9500.8    164.3     13004.2   54644.1
20200522  9940.9    203.6     20142.7   49401.3
20210521  11226.3   222.7     14085.7   54759
20220527  13605.5   380.1     19472.8   46403.6
20220701  13206.5   376.3     12784     53552.9
20220706  13148.9   272.6     13455.7   51796.4
20221006  13832.9   311.6     13006.1   52337.4
20230309  13389.8   310.5     12677     54125.9
20230907  13806.3   334.8     13381.2   54700.4
20240919  15376.2   492.4     13050.4   53682.1


# long
date      RH        LH        RA        LA
20200203  9070.1    236.9     5505.8    53849.7
20200522  9489.2    258.5     6505.8    54003.9
20220527  13466     441.1     14128.5   50221.7
20220701  12934.3   400.4     14421.3   52927
20220706  12921.9   386.5     14539.9   50843.7
20221006  13440.1   351.2     15709.2   50322.8
20230309  13258.9   362.8     14416.2   52378.4
20210521  10771.3   294.8     14199.1   53795.7
20230907  13369.6   376.7     14974.9   53158.1
20240919  15216     478.7     14213     51990.8
EOD

myHeaders     = "LH RH LA RA"
H             = words(myHeaders)
dataHeader(i) = column(word(myHeaders, i))
myBlocks      = "cross long"
B             = words(myBlocks)
myBlock(i)    = word(myBlocks, i)
myBoxwidth    =  0.8
myFmt         = "%Y%m%d"
t(col,i)      = ((timecolumn(col,myFmt)-t0)/(t1-t0) - 0.5)*myBoxwidth + i

stats $DAT u (timecolumn(1,myFmt)) nooutput
t0 = STATS_min
t1 = STATS_max

set title "dat -> ref" font "Arial,14"
set style boxplot outliers pointtype 7
set style data boxplot
set xrange [0.5:H+0.5] noextend
set logscale y
set grid y,my
set style fill solid 1.0 border -1
set boxwidth myBoxwidth absolute
set key left top reverse noautotitle

set linetype 1 lc rgb 0xaaff0000
set linetype 2 lc rgb 0xaa00aa00
set linetype 3 lc rgb 0x77ffff00

plot for [i=1:H] $REF index "norm" u (i):(dataHeader(i)) lt 3, \
     for [b=1:B] for [i=1:H] $DAT index myBlock(b) u (t(1,i)):(dataHeader(i)) w lp pt 7 lt b, \
     for [b=1:B] keyentry w lp pt 7 lt b ti myBlock(b), \
     keyentry w boxes lt 3 ti "Ref", \
     for [i=1:H] '+' every ::::0 u (i):(NaN):xtic(word(myHeaders, i)) w p
### end of script

Result:


Great! That's a perfect solution. However, the times don't seem to be sorted chronologically, yet. I have added an example image of a single box. Timepoint 3 is skipped first, but later connected between points 8 and 9.

@magfan ok, well, that's how the input data is: in datablock $DAT subblock # long 20230309 is followed by 20210521 and then 20230907. In subblock # cross it seems to be in chronological order. So, could the data be in random order and you are asking for sorting it first? It might be better to have it sorted in the input data already, but with some workarounds you could also sort it within gnuplot. I expected the dates to be identical (in value and order) in # cross and # long.

Sorry. This seems to be an error when copying and pasting. In the original file, the times are sorted chronologically. So it was my mistake when I wrote the original script.

For some files, the date/time is encoded in a character string, e.g. "subject_name/20221006085330_test_something". The following function returns the date (in this case "20221006"):
get_date(c)  = substr( strcol(c), strstrt( strcol(c), "/" ) + 1, strstrt( strcol(c), "/" ) + 8 )
How can this function be used together with
stats $DAT u (timecolumn(1,myFmt)) nooutput
Replacing "1" with "get_date(1)" does not work, and I cannot explain the meaning of this error:
unknown type in magnitude()

@magfan this is a completely different topic... and comments probably too short to give a reasonable answer. If you haven't found a similar question on SO, please open a new question with such a minimal example.
